# How do I view model.feature_importances_ output with the names of the features?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I've built a DecisionTreeClassifier model in python and would like to see the importance of each feature.  As I'm using sklearn I've converted all my classes to numbers. Here's how I've imported the data:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv('Video_Games_Sales_as_at_22_Dec_2016.csv')
no_na_df = raw_data.dropna(how='any')
```

after getting rid of NAs I created my DF for numeric conversion:

```
numeric_df = no_na_df.copy()
cols = ['Platform','Genre','Publisher','Developer','Rating']
numeric_df[cols] = numeric_df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]+1)
```

Once that's done, I created the test and train split:

```
X = numeric_df.drop(['Name','Global_Sales_Bin','Global_Sales','NA_Sales','EU_Sales','JP_Sales','Other_Sales'], axis = 1)
y = numeric_df['Global_Sales_Bin']

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)
```

ran the model etc, got my results, and then I wanted to see the importance of each feature:

```
model.feature_importances_
```

which output this:

```
array([ 0.08518705,  0.07874186,  0.06322593,  0.08446309,  0.08410844,
        0.08097326,  0.07744228,  0.1851621 ,  0.23597441,  0.02472158])
```

I don't know how to match up the features in the model with the numbers above. both 'X' and 'model' are stored as numpy arrays and the orginal dataframe has been cut down to fit the model so the features don't align properly. I think I might have to use a for loop and zip, but not sure how.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this example, which is about this exact problem: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but it doesn't 100% solve my problem. I get a list of "feature #" and the importance, but I need to know the name of the feature, i.e. "Publisher", "Developer", "Platform" etc. I've been trying to reverse engineer this solution to fit what I already have but can't make it work, I'm still pretty new to python.

Comment: In that example, when they print the feature importances, just replace `indices[f]` with `column[indices[f]]`  where `column` is a list of columns you sent to the model to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks for the help however I still couldn't get it to work. I ended up using this: `list(zip(X_columns, model.feature_importances_))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up working `list(zip(X_columns, model.feature_importances_))`

```
X_columns = X.columns
```

Output:

```
[('Platform', 0.085187050413710552),
 ('Year_of_Release', 0.078741862224430401),
 ('Genre', 0.063225925635322172),
 ('Publisher', 0.084463091000316695),
 ('Critic_Score', 0.084108440698256848),
 ('Critic_Count', 0.080973259803115372),
 ('User_Score', 0.077442278687036153),
 ('User_Count', 0.18516210213713488),
 ('Developer', 0.23597440837370295),
 ('Rating', 0.024721581026973961)]
```